# Rep requirements impeading content quality

Tags: discussion

I noticed when posting a question, a new user can't post images or more than 2 links in a question. While this is sensible as bad things could happen, this doesn't prevent `somethingbad dot com slash bad stuff` from happening.

The issue is that censorship feels limiting, especially to users who have registered but haven't participated actively yet. What if the question is a graphics question dealing with layers? I feel that the rep-system is quite limiting for lurkers who view a lot of content but don't necessarily contribute much themselves. I can understand limiting anons, as this would be too much to monitor, but I feel like registered users should be more trusted, especially if they have accounts on other stack exchanges.

The question:
Should we trust users who have rep on other SE sites with more posting abilities?

Comment: If a registered user has 100 rep on any SE site, they get 100 rep on stack overflow (documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)).

Comment: @Blorgbeard They have to have 200 reputation to get the bonus, not 100.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw my mistake, you're correct.

Comment: I would love it if they could upload things as links and images, but those get parsed out as plain text (not hyperlinks) to the image/linked site. Then they could get tossed in the "first post" queue to get reviewed by folks (and displayed with images and links). Fantastic. I find myself editing that stuff in when I see a post without them anyway, why not make a process for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It only takes ten reputation for those restrictions to be lifted; if a new user's first post is able to get even two upvotes (one if it's an answer), that is enough that they can then go back, edit their post, and add any images/links they couldn't add the first time around. If their post can't stand on its own without a bunch of links and images, then it's probably not a very good post anyway. And the restrictions are very useful in limiting spam posts by new or unregistered users.

Comment: Accepted for "If their post can't stand on its own without a bunch of links and images, then it's probably not a very good post anyway."